# JRuby: Documentation of mappings/conversions between Java and Ruby types/classes?

Tags: jruby

I am writing a Java wrapper library around a ruby gem so I am embedding ruby within Java and not the other way around. I seem to be in the vast minority!

If I have a ruby method that returns a `Time` object then I can very easily convert it into a `java.util.Date` object on the Java side like this:

```java
public Date getStartTime() {
    IRubyObject result = RuntimeHelpers.invoke(runtime.getCurrentContext(),
        this, "start_time");
    return (Date) result.toJava(Date.class);
}
```

But I think I got lucky working this out by trial and error and not all like-seeming types can be converted in this way. I have another ruby method that returns a `URI` object (it could be a `URI::HTTP` or a `URI::HTTPS` in fact) but trying the obvious (given the above) conversion to a `java.net.URI` doesn't work (I also tried it with `java.net.URL`):

```java
public URI getUri() {
    IRubyObject result = RuntimeHelpers.invoke(runtime.getCurrentContext(),
        this, "uri");
    return (URI) result.toJava(URI.class);
}
```

This code compiles, but fails at run time:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (TypeError) cannot
convert instance of class org.jruby.RubyObject to class java.net.URI
```

I realise that in ruby a `URI` is actually a module and `URI::HTTPS`, etc are the classes, so I'm not entirely surprised that the above didn't work. But there's clearly a bit of internal "magic" being done for the `Time`/`Date` example so I was wondering if there were similar conversions provided for other types, which types and where they are documented.

Any pointers much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/CallingJavaFromJRuby says "Conversion of Types – Ruby to Java – *See the JRuby rspec source code dir `spec/java_integration` for many more examples.* [examples, ...]".

Sure enough, [`coercion_spec.rb`](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/blob/master/spec/java_integration/types/coercion_spec.rb) contains a lot of examples/specifications. Here's the case you already use:

```
describe "Time\"to_java" do
  describe "when passed java.util.Date" do
    it "coerces to java.util.Date" do
      t = Time.now
      d = t.to_java(java.util.Date)
      d.class.should == java.util.Date
    end
  end

  # [...]
end
```

I believe this is the best documentation currently available.

Comment: That is a good spot, thanks. Naturally, as I'm calling Ruby from Java, I didn't think to look on that "side" of the documentation! I have since managed to add enough code to JRuby for auto-coercion of the Ruby URI classes into Java URI objects but it was hard going and would take a lot of work to get it "done properly" - if it's even appropriate to do it that way.